# Same CSS for whole site, but text boldness changes

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with design side. I have one main.css and few html pages, like index.html, contact.html and other. They are all in one folder, they ar all linked to main.css correctly. Lastly, I am using google fonts. So in index.html I have pretty great looking text like this:

[image: Here is what I want text to look like in other pages]

But what I get in other page is:

[image: This is what it looks like in other pages]

I know that it's not a big difference, but I want text to look consistent in whole site.

Here are parts of CSS that i think are important:

```
/* This is what makes it look like what I want */
content #turinys{
  position: absolute;
  margin: 25vh 3.5vw 5vh 7vw;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  z-index: -1;
}

content #turinys h1{
  font-size: 12vh;
  color: #F57C00;
}

content #turinys h2{
  font-size: 8vh;
}


/* This is what I made in other page */

content #kontaktai{
  position: absolute;
  margin: 15vh 3.5vw 5vh 7vw;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  float: left;
}

content #kontaktai h2{
  font-size: 8vh;
}
```

I know that font-size is different, but as I tried to make it the same it still didn't made text look the same.

Could someone help?

UPDATE: Here is my HTML of page where everything is as I want.

```
<content>
  <div id="turinys">
    <h2>Hi, I am</h2><br>
    <h1>Arminas,</h1><br>
    <h2>a Web Developer.</h2>
    <p>This is my portfolio. Currently working with <span>HTML</span>, <span>CSS</span>, <span>JavaScript</span>. Going to learn <span>PHP</span>, <span>SQL</span>, <span>Python</span>.<br>
      Studying at Vilniaus Gediminas technical university. Multimedia and Computer Design.<br>
      <span>Passionate</span> about web design and development. Want to make all the <span>internet</span> look good.</p>
    <form action="contact.html">
      <input type="submit" value="CONTACT ME" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="turinysImg">
    <img src="logo.png">
  </div>
</content>
```

Here is HTML code where nothing makes sense.

```
<content>
  <div id="kontaktai">
    <h2 class="noselect">I am based in
    <span>Vilnius</span></h2><br><br>
    <p class="noselect"><span>Contact</span> me if you want to <span>work</span> or <span>discuss</span> something with me:</p><br><br>
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="vardas" placeholder="Name">
      <input type="text" name="telefonas" placeholder="Phone Number"><br><br>
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"><br><br>
      <textarea rows="16" cols="64" placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="map"></div>
</content>
```

SOLVED:

Fine, I was too fast to ask a question without trying everything that could change something.

So the problem was I had Google Maps in there and somehow they interfered with other css on that page. I will UPDATE this when I will find where it changed text.

Comment: As @lowry0031 mentioned, there may be other CSS being applied.  It would help to create a [MWE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example) that highlights the issue.  Most likely, you could overcome this with an `!important` flag, but more details would make for a better answer.

Comment: @D.N. I can't overcome this with !important, because I didn't change anything, I copied CSS block and it was already different. Font was bold in the begining withou any font-weight changes. I can assume it may be something wrong because it is google font.

Comment: Also, funny thing, when I refresh page, for a short period of time  it looks like it should, and then it becomes thinner.

Comment: It's hard to identify the issue without seeing all of the content of the rendered pages, including their CSS links and all declarations within the CSS file.  To keep the size smaller and to reduce personal information, it is easiest to create an MWE.  The idea is to have the absolute bare minimum to recreate the issue, so troubleshooting becomes easier.  You may very well find that during this endeavor, you stumble upon the reason yourself.  Unfortunately, the way you've provided details as of right now, we still don't have enough information to identify the root issue.